# Touch position highlight

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to highlight a touch event by using `UIGestureRecognizer`, so far I can get the `CGPoint` where the user touched but I don't know how to highlight that specific area since I don't know much about animation.

The code so far on `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gradientTouchDown:)];

[self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

The method that gets the position of the touch:

```
-(void)gradientTouchDown:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"tap detected.");
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:nil];

    NSLog(@"x = %f y = %f", point.x, point.y );

}
```

By doing some study I think I need to add the code above with a View animation, but how can I recognize the touch? the code:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^
     {
         [sender setAlpha:0.3f];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [sender setAlpha:1.0f];
     }];
```

I really need help on this one, any question just ask, I'm always around here :)

Comment: Have you tried to create a view, set its frame, use a block animation to fade it in and then fade it out and remove it from the superview?

Comment: Here's a good place to start (rather than asking pointlessly open ended questions on StackOverflow): [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Can you tell what kind of animation you're looking for? Just a dot or shape where the user taps, or a path as the user pans ?

Comment: I have used something like this:   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^
     {
         [sender setAlpha:0.3f];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [sender setAlpha:1.0f];
     }];

Comment: The animation is simple, just a highlight on touch :)

Comment: It maybe pointless for you middaparka but not for me, thanks for the downvote anyway :)

Comment: Firstly, you substantially altered your question after I posted my comment to include what you'd attempted to date (hence proving that you weren't simply fishing for some code), secondly my point was that there's no value in being simply told what to do when you can trivially find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thanks for the help, I came out with a custom solution for a similar glow effect related to the Apple "Shows Touch on Highlight" here is the code for the glow:

```
-(void)gradientTouchDown:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"tap detected");
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:nil];


    NSLog(@"x = %f y = %f", point.x, point.y );


    UIImage* image;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(recognizer.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); {
        [recognizer.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, recognizer.view.bounds.size.width, recognizer.view.bounds.size.height)];

        [color setFill];

        [path fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop alpha:1.0];


        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    } UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIView* glowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    glowView.center = self.center;
    [self.superview insertSubview:glowView aboveSubview:self];

    glowView.alpha = 0;
    glowView.layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor;
    glowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    glowView.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
    glowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;


    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = @(0.0f);
    animation.toValue = @(0.6f);
    //animation.repeatCount = 2 ? HUGE_VAL : 0;
    animation.duration = 0.2;
    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [glowView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pulse"];


}
```

Any suggestion for improvement is welcome, so far it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented my animation in one of my projects for a button. The animation just puts a glow around the button when pressed (just like the glow you see when you press an year button on the graph view of built in stocks app)

First, add these targets to the button:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then these methods looks like this:

```
- (void) myButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    CABasicAnimation *shadowRadius = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius" ];
    shadowRadius.delegate = self;
    [shadowRadius setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0]];
    [shadowRadius setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0]];
    [shadowRadius setDuration:0.2f];

    [[button layer] addAnimation:shadowRadius forKey:@"shadowRadius"];

    button.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0f;
}
- (void) myButtonReleased:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    CABasicAnimation *shadowRadius = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius" ];
    shadowRadius.delegate = self;
    [shadowRadius setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0]];
    [shadowRadius setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0]];
    [shadowRadius setDuration:0.2f];
    //shadowRadius.autoreverses = YES;

    [[button layer] addAnimation:shadowRadius forKey:@"shadowRadius"];

    button.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    button.selected = YES;
}
```